# VBA dont find my Sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have this part of code in vba in Excel to past value from cliboard:

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add

SheetName= "New One"
Sheets("New One").Range("A11").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

And I have this problem: `error '9' Subscript out of range`.

If I change the sheet name to a technical name like `sheet19`, work well, but I don't know the technical name of the sheet that is being created in the moment.

How can I solve this?
Thks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

> ```
> SheetName= "New One"
> ```

Into

```
WS.Name= "New One"
```

Your statement is not changing the name of the sheet, but just assigning a variable. Also, since you have a reference on the sheet, that is `WS`, why invoke it again by the name, why not just

```
WS.Range("A11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim WS          As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName   As String

    Set WS = Sheets.Add
    WS.Name = "New One"
    WS.Range("A11") = 45
    'Alternative:        
    Worksheets(WS.Name).Range("A15") = 46

End Sub
```

Refer to `WS` later, or use `Worksheets(WS.Name)`. Do not use `Sheets`, because it also refers to `Charts`, if you have some.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    ws.Name= "New One"
    ws.Range("A11").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your range is wrongly defined.

It must be something like this Range(Cells(x1,y1),Cells(x2,y2))

Also if it a constructed worksheet at run time, you may need to use ThisWorkbook or ActiveSheet references.

Try changing your range in above format and let me know.